# skin is not a known element (angular)

Tags: angular

I think, I got lost in the angular component world. I'm trying to make a popup form with a tab panel and some tabs (the header is hidden), where the tabs will be separate components. In an other part of the app, I did this already and it works fine, so, I thought, I have just to copy the approach.

The details:

I have a skin component (which will be a tab content) with this module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SkinComponent } from './skin.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [SkinComponent],
  declarations: [SkinComponent]
})
export class SkinModule { }
```

Then, I have the `settings` component with the tab panel, where I have the `skin` element like this:

```
<dx-tab-panel #tabPanel
                style="float: left"
                [dataSource]="tabs"
                [selectedIndex]="0">
    <div *dxTemplate="let a of 'a'">
      wwww
    </div>
    <div *dxTemplate="let skin of 'skin'">
      <skin></skin>
    </div>
    <div *dxTemplate="let c of 'c'">
      dddd
    </div>
  </dx-tab-panel>
```

In order to use the `skin` element, I imported the `SkinModule` in the `settings` module like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { SkinModule } from './skin/skin.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SkinModule],
  exports: [],
  declarations: []
})
export class SettingsModule { }
```

And then the `SettingsModule` is imported in another module, but this is not relevant now.

Now, my understanding is, that I exported the `SkinComponent` in the `SkinModule` and imported the `SkinModule` in the `SettingsModule`. So, the `SettingsComponent` should know the `SkinComponent`. But it doesn't.

I have a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ueyzwz?file=src/app/components/settings/settings.component.html) for you, where it clearly says, that the `skin` element is unknown. Curiously, on my computer if I build the angular app, I don't get this error, it compiles whithout any error, but the skin element doesn't show.

What do I wrong?

Comment: try exporting SkinComponent from SettingsModule also.

Comment: just add skinModule in exports array in **settings.module.ts** like this `@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SkinModule],
  exports: [SkinModule],
  declarations: []
})`

Comment: And indeed. But as I wrote in my question, I don't really unterstand, why I need this in this case, and didn't need this in the other cases. F. e. look at the companies.module.ts in the masterdata/general/companies folder. This is a component, which is in a tab in the general.component.html. And in the general.module.ts I Import the companies.module but don't export it too.